# How can I get the timezone of files and directories via terminal command?

Tags: files, terminal, filesystems, timezone

For example, I create a file and directory in the timezone in New York.

Then I change the timezone in the system to London (UK), but still want to know which file and directory is created in which timezone. Is there a terminal command for Unix to display it?

Comment: Related: [Is time zone information saved in files?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/33465)

Comment: Thanks for the help. 

but when I change the timezone, why does stat command in terminal show me a different time? Example: stat hello.txt
Apr 7 07:40:01 2021 (original timezone)
Apr 7 15:40:01 2021 (timezone was changed in system)
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possibly you can tell your `stat` to recalculate to any timezone, even a "fake" one, e.g. `TZ=foo+5 stat hello.txt` or `TZ=bar-2:15 stat hello.txt`. The fact `stat` uses your current (or requested) timezone is not a problem, it's a feature. :) The information in your filesystem is most likely totally timezone-agnostic.

Comment: I understand, but is there a way to change the behavior. I want stat or other command to always show me the original timezone, regardless of what timezone I changed in the system. I am currently using FreeBSD 13 and have not found a command in Terminal that solves this problem. Can you help me? Or is it a feature Request for the kernel in FreeBSD or a filesystem problem? I am using OpenZFS as a filesystem.

Comment: This would be a feature request, and it would mean such a deep change to the code of all filesystem types for almost no benefit that it would not be considered. There are many other pieces of environmental information that are not stored: The value of PATH, or the current temperature, or the deviation of your clock from the NTP server, or the kernel version when the file was created, ... Nobody is interested in this.

Answer (score 2):

The timezone is not recorded in files and directories. Timestamps are expressed as the number of seconds since midnight, Jan 1, 1970 UTC (a moment in time often referred to as "the epoch").

Comment: But when I change the timezone from New York to London, it shows me a different time in terminal and at that moment I no longer know where I created the file and directory, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: The programs that show the time take the file's timestamps and display them according to your time zone setting. By the way, not all filesystems record the creation time; as far as I know POSIX only defines inode change time, file access time and file modification time.

Comment: I don't know what your problem is. If your current time zone is set to GMT, and the timestamp is shown as April 1st, 8am, it means April 1st 8am GMT, or April 1st 3am EST, or April 1st 5pm, JST (I hope my calculation is correct).

Comment: Example: stat hello.txt Apr 7 07:40:01 2021 (original timezone) -> timezone was changed in system -> stat hello.txt Apr 7 15:40:01 2021. Now when I want to know later which file and directory is created in which timezone, I don't know anymore. This is the problem. How can I solve this problem? Yes I want to change the system timezone, but not that the file and directories adjust to the system timezone, only if I want to.

Comment: Files and directories don't adjust to the time zone. Commands you use to view their timestamps do. You can change their behaviour with the TZ variable; e.g. `TZ=Asia/Tokyo ls -l`, but unfortunately the value of the TZ variable or the system-wide time zone at creation time are not recorded.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to berndbausch's answer, I'd like to post the output `stat` from a file on my system:

```
$ stat a.out
  File: a.out
  Size: 16632           Blocks: 40         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 831h/2097d      Inode: 17827331    Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/    stew)   Gid: ( 1000/    stew)
Access: 2021-04-07 16:13:49.880038403 +0200
Modify: 2020-12-20 21:23:03.206200984 +0100
Change: 2020-12-20 21:23:03.206200984 +0100
 Birth: 2020-12-20 21:23:03.194201098 +0100
```

If we're interested in creation date, that's "Birth".  You can see the time is:

```
2020-12-20 21:23:03.194201098 +0100
```

Disregard the date and seconds for the moment and focus on the rest.  That time is **21:23 +0100**.  That means it was created at **21:23** in a **UTC+1h** timezone.  This would be 20:23 UTC.

By contrast, you can see that it was last accessed at **16:13** in a **UTC+2h** timezone. The difference in timezones is related to daylight savings time.  This would be at **14:13 UTC**.

Unix time only tracks the number of seconds since the epoch (UTC).  That number is converted to a local time whenever it needs to be human readable and is usually based on the current time-zone configured by the system.  It actually surprised me a little that the time-zone was saved in the stat.

Comment: To be clear: your `stat` seems to use two different offsets because your current timezone setting includes information about DST. This means some (epoch) timestamps are *displayed* according to `+0200` and some other according to `+0100`. It depends on what offset your current setting specifies for the moment of the respective timestamp. I think if you run `TZ=foo-2 stat a.out` then you will get `+0200` in every field. Your result has nothing to do with some timezone allegedly having been saved. It's only a "translation" of timezone-agnostic timestamps according to your *current* setting.

Comment: I totally agree that the difference is meerly how it's *displayed* and not how it's stored.

Comment: I wanted (1) to address the "surprise" factor; (2) and not to give the OP false hope that some timezone-related information is saved (the last sentence of your answer may be interpreted this way).

Comment: `stat` must have 'deduced' what timezone I was in when that file was saved based on DST rules.  That was my surprise.

Comment: Not quite. The timezone you *actually was in* is irrelevant and never tried to be deduced. You could have been in any timezone and the current output of `stat` would be the same (assuming your current timezone setting would be what it is). Your `stat` displayed all timestamps according to your current setting, not according to your current offset (with respect to UTC). The setting specifies *two offsets* (one of them is DST). Some timestamps translate to the current setting so the results are shown with one offset, some translate to results shown with the other offset.

Comment: In other words `stat` displays what you would have considered your then-current time and offset at the time of the respective timestamp, if your timezone setting at the time was exactly what it is now (or what you tell `stat` to use with `TZ=…`). The tool absolutely does not attempt to deduce what your timezone *actually* was.